# Как получить с помощью функции несколько значений?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю книгу по JS и не могу понять, почему нижеприведенный код из книги возвращает массив [NaN, NaN]?

```js
function getSize(width, height, depth) {
      let area = width * height;
      let volume = width * height * depth;
      let sizes = [area, volume];
      return sizes;
    }
let areaOne = getSize(3,2,3)[0];
let volumeOne = getSize(3,2,3)[1];

console.log(areaOne);
console.log(volumeOne);
```

При вызове функции getSize я должен получить массив значений, где в индексе 0 будет вычисленное значение areaOne, а в индексе 1 volumeOne.

Comment: с приведённым кодом всё нормально. скорее всего ты умолчал о каких-то ещё вводных данных

Comment: Если я в консоле пишу getSize(), то в ответ получаю [NaN, NaN], а должен, как я понимаю, получить [6, 18]

Comment: если ты пишешь `getSize()` без передачи данных, то логично получаешь кукиш. Или на чём в таком случае должна считать данные? Читать мысли она не умеет

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. В этом примере меня смутило, что после тела функции мы объявили две переменные areaOne и volumeOne, когда можно было просто при вызове функции getSize внутри передать аргументы вот так: getSize(3,2,3) и тогда получаем массив [6,18].

Comment: Всё верно. потом результат этот можно было записать в две переменные, а не вызывать два раза фукнкцию

Comment: А можно вообще вот так написать `let [myVar2, myVar2] = getSize(3,2,3)` и тогда  получим сразу две новых переменных и сложим туда данные из функции (в каждую переменную своё значение) ... но лучше возвращать в таком случае объект. Это читабельнее, чем гадать что в масиве под индексом 0, а что под индексом 1